# Can I formulate the factor model in another way to overcome the drawback of the classical factor model?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, pca, factor-analysis

In classical factor model, assume the random vector $X = (X_1, \cdots, X_p)$ has the covariance matrix $\Sigma$, we want to write $X$ in the form $X = LF + e$, the assumptions are $Var(F) = I_r, Cov(F, e) = 0, Var(e) = \text{diag}(\sigma_1^2, \cdots, \sigma_p^2)$. To solve the classical factor model, we need to find the solution of $\Sigma = LL' + \Psi$, where $L$is a $p\times r$ matrix, $\Psi$ is a diagonal matrix. However sometimes, there is no solutions to the equation!

The reason is that the assumption $Var(e)$ is a diagonal is very strong. So can we consider to remove this assumption i.e. the error terms can be mutually correlated. For this reason, I came up with another formulation of the factor model, we still write $X$ in the form $X = LF + e$, but the assumptions are $Var(F) = I_r, Cov(F, e) = 0$, our goal is to maximize the variance that the factors can be explained, that is
$$
\max_{L \in \mathbb{R}^{p\times r}} ~ ~ \text{tr}(LL') 
$$
under the condition $\Psi = \Sigma - LL'$ is a non-negative definite matrix. A solution to $L$ can be derived by the spectral decomposition of $\Sigma$.

So I wander to know whether this formulation has any issues? Or does anyone has already propose a similar formulation?